# octave history command - variable as filename

Tags: octave

i want to write little helper functions that stores and loads the octave session.

```
function restoreSession(filename)
  history -r strcat('./states/',filename,'.history');
  load("-binary", strcat('./states/',filename,'.data')) 
endfunction


function saveSession(filename)
  history -w strcat('./states/',filename,'.history');
  save("-binary", strcat('./states/',filename,'.data')) 
endfunction
```

The save/load command works well. 
My Problem is that the history command seems not to evaulate the argument.
it prodces the following error:

```
  syntax error

>>>   history -r strcat('./states/',filename,'.history');
                                                       ^
```

I already tried to use a temporary var for the path but in this case it only interprets the variable name as filename and complains about the missing file.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `history` with the function syntax instead of a command.

```
history ("-r", strcat ("./states/", filename, ".history"));
```

All commands are actually functions. The command syntax (when you don't use parentheses) is available to all functions, it just happens that for some it looks more natural. When you omit the parentheses, all the arguments are interpreted as strings, even variable names. If you want to do something fancier, call them as functions.

Comment: ok thanks. i was not aware of that fact. but it still does not work. it seems that the calls of load and history does not have any affect to the world outside of function

Comment: @vlad_tepesch you can use `evalin ("caller", ...) to make it have effect on the scope of the caller.

Comment: thanks, but how to apply this on history or load and save command? My saveSession restoreSession are more scripts than functions but require file name parameter.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch no they are not. They are functions. Just turn your function calls to `history`, `save` and `load`, into calls to `evalin`.

Comment: thanks, i got it: `evalin("caller", strcat("history( '-r', './states/",filename,".history')"));`